# I keep getting: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insert' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js, meteor-autoform, collectionfs

I am using cfs-filesystem with the autoform and I have set it up using both the documentation in the collectionFS and meteor-cfs-autoform but I am getting the error above when i try to submit a form creating a record for my school collections. I am not sure what I am missing or where the error is getting generated

common.js:

```
// File methods
 Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
  stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem("images", {path: "~/img/uploads"})]
 });

 Images.allow({
  download: function () {
  return true;
},
fetch: null
});
```

school_collection.js:

```
Schools = new Mongo.Collection("Schools");


//Defining the schema
Schools.attachSchema(schoolSchema = new SimpleSchema({
name: {
type:String,
label: "Name",
max:200
},
primary_color: {
 type:String,
 label: "Color",
 optional: true
},
sub_domain: {
 type:String,
 label: "Sub Domain",
 max:50
},
user_id:{
 type: String,
 autoform: {
  type: "hidden",
  label: false
},
autoValue: function(){
  if (this.isInsert) {
        return Meteor.userId();
    } else if (this.isUpsert) {
        return {$setOnInsert: Meteor.userId()};
    } else {
        this.unset();
    }
  },
denyUpdate:true
},
image: {
 type: String,
 label: "Logo",
 autoform: {
   afFieldInput: {
     type: "cfs-file",
     collection: "files"
   }
 }
} 
}));
```

school_create.html

```
School Create


{{#autoForm collection="Schools" id="school_create" type="insert"}}

  Add a School




      {{> afQuickField name='name'}}




      {{> afQuickField name='sub_domain'}}







    {{> afQuickField name="image"}}



Add a School
{{/autoForm}}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborare a simple demo on meteorpad of this?